# Copy Elision and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11

in the code below, what it is used to avoid copy, elision or rvalue reference and move constructor ?

```
std::string get(){return "...";}

void foo(std::string var){}

foo( get() ); //<--- here
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::string get(){
    // this is similar to return std::string("..."), which is
    // copied/moved into the return value object.
    return "...";
}
```

RVO allows it to construct the temporary string object directly into the return value object of `get()`.

```
foo( get() );
```

RVO allows it to directly construct the temporary string object (the return value object) directly into the parameter object of `foo`.

These are the RVO scenarios allowed. If your compiler cannot apply them, it *has* to use move constructors (if available) to move the return value into the return value object and the parameter object, respectively. In this case that is not surprising because both temporary objects are or are treated as rvalues anyway. (For the first scenario, no expression corresponds to the created temporary, so the treatment is only for the purpose of selecting what constructor is used for copying/moving the temporary into the return value object).

For other cases, the compiler has to consider things as rvalues even if they are otherwise lvalues

```
std::string get(){
    std::string s = "...";
    // this is similar to return move(s)
    return s;
}
```

The spec says when it could potentially apply RVO (or NRVO) to an lvalue by the rules it sets forth, the implementation is required to treat the expressions as rvalues and use move constructors if available, and only if it couldn't find a suitable constructor, it should use the expression as an lvalue. It would be a pity for the programmer to write explicit moves in these cases, when it's clear the programmer would always want a move instead of a copy.

Example:

```
struct A { A(); A(A&); };
struct B { B(); B(B&&); };

A f() { A a; return a; }
B f() { B b; return b; }
```

For the first, it takes `a` as an rvalue, but cannot find constructors that accept this rvalue (`A&` cannot bind to rvalues). Therefor, it then again treats `a` as what it is (an lvalue). For the second, it takes `b` as a rvalue, and has `B(B&&)` take that rvalue and move it. If it would have taken `b` as an lvalue (what it is), then the copy initialization would have failed, because `B` has no copy constructor implicitly declared.

---

Note that returning and paramter passing uses the rules of copy initialization, which means

```
u -> T (where u's type is different from T) =>
  T rvalue_tmp = u;
  T target(rvalue_tmp);

t -> T (where t's type is T) =>
  T target = t;
```

Hence, in the example where we return a `"..."`, we first create an rvalue temporary and then move that into the target. For the case where we return an expression of the type of the return value / paramter, we will directly move / copy the expression into the target.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely copy ellision, but if your compiler cannot apply in this case, which can happen if the functions are more complex, then you're looking at a move. Moves are extremely efficient, so I wouldn't panic here if ellision is not performed.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation defined, but *most likely* copy elision.

Similarly, RVO/NRVO will most likely kick in before move semantics when returning an object value from a function.